# Mysql - show more detail in result of query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT MIN(temperature) 
FROM temperature 
WHERE sensor_id = '28-0316387a1eff' 
AND DATE(`dtg`) = CURDATE()
```

This works in that it shows me the minimum temperature for the current day.
How do I get it to show me the time at which this occurred?

Column `dtg` uses `current_timestamp`.

Thank you.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

You could select the row where temperature = min(temperature)

```
select `dtg`, temperature
from temperature
where temperature = (
    SELECT MIN(temperature) 
    FROM temperature 
    WHERE sensor_id = '28-0316387a1eff' 
    AND DATE(`dtg`) = CURDATE()
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be faster not to use a sub select. Better try this:

```
select t.dtg ,t.temperature
from temperature t
WHERE t.sensor_id = '28-0316387a1eff' 
AND DATE(t.dtg) = CURDATE()
order by t.temperature 
limit 1
```

Comment: That works nicely. How does it work, what are the the 't.' parts and what do they do?  Thank you.

Comment: It is just a short way to refer to temperature table. So you do not have to write temperature.sensor_id, but you write t.sensor_id